# Localized System.Windows.Media.Color name

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

The standard color names are english names, ok. But my Application is german so I would like to have the color names in my `ComboBox` as german names. Instead of "Blue", "Yellow", etc. I would like to have "Blau", "Gelb", etc.

Is there a function that returns all localized names? Or is it that easy that I change the culture in this call?

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Type}"
                    x:Key="colorsTypeOdp">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <sys:String>System.Windows.Media.Colors, PresentationCore,
    Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</sys:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a useful table that gives me some Translations (english names and german ones) [The table can be found here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180419233623/http://farbe-computer.de/kapitel33.html).

I will use the texts and a Converter to display the German color names.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up to peetee's question and link to [this German page about Netscape color names](https://web.archive.org/web/20180419233623/http://farbe-computer.de/kapitel33.html), I've built [a small C# wrapper class](http://pastebin.com/sKtpjHND) that you can drop-into your project.

To use, simply call it something similar to:

```
string germanName = ColorNameGermanTranslator.GetGermanName(Color.Green);
```

and you get the German name back. It uses the English name as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the code snippet was gone  ... so here it is:

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Type}"
                    x:Key="colorsTypeOdp">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <sys:String>System.Windows.Media.Colors, PresentationCore,
    Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</sys:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, these are property names -- as much part of the code / class definition as the String.Length property -- not resources.  Property names aren't localised.