# Localizing color names in C#

Tags: c#, localization, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localized System.Windows.Media.Color name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240300/localized-system-windows-media-color-name)

Does anyone know of any library which would help with localizing the color names for the System.Drawing.Color named colors? I need them in German currently, but more languages later.

Comment: `System.Color`? Do you mean `System.Drawing.Color` or `System.Windows.Media.Color`?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240300/localized-system-windows-media-color-name).

Comment: I guess the question states clearly that System.Color is the one that Joel is interested in. This is not a duplicate of question related to WPF then.

Comment: @Pawel, [there is no type named](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) `System.Color`.

Comment: @Frédéric: You are right and I am tired. Still, I doubt he meant WPF.

Comment: sorry - I meant System.Drawing.Color, edited.

Comment: translate them, add them to the resources and dynamically pull them out at runtime.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? How is the localized text being used?

Comment: Colors used in a CAD file are shown in a list. If they have a name, it is used, but the property name is naturally English.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more looking around turned up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240300/localized-system-windows-media-color-name), with a link to [this list of colors](http://farbe-computer.de/kapitel33.html). This is the best I have found so far, but it is still just a list of German-English colors rather than a library.

Comment: Wait a sec, you just answered your own question with the link to the dupe from my second comment, right? ;)

Comment: oh yeah! didn't notice, sorry. Still not a great answer though :(

Comment: I've created [a small wrapper class for German translation of color names](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19782143/107625).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this site: http://german.about.com/library/blfarben_voc.htm

Comment: I was looking for a library rather than a dictionary... I will need other languages in due course, and wondered whether this was an already solved problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is not gonna be a library or dictionary that covers all languages, your gonna need to specify what you want.

Comment: Well, Microsoft have an excellent record on localizing their stuff, so I thought it was worth asking. They even localize their macro language for Word :/ - which has caused us no end of hassle.